# 1の補数とmemsetについて

Tags: c

c言語における1の補数について、signed char型(8bitとします)の-2をunsigned char型にキャストした場合、`1111 1101`から`1111 1110`にビットパターンが変化すると理解しているのですが、この理解は正しいでしょうか？

また、iso c99ではmemset関数は次のようになっていました

> 7.21.6.1 memset関数
> 形式
> #include <string.h>
> void *memset(void *s, int c, size̲t n);
> 機能 memset関数は，c（unsigned char型に型変換する。）の値を，sが指すオブジェクトの最初のn文字のそれぞれにコピーする。

私の1の補数の理解が正しいなら、次のコードは2の補数の処理系では`1`，1の補数の処理系では`0`が出力されるのではないかと疑問に思いました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    signed char *s = malloc(sizeof(signed char) * 1);
    if (s == NULL)
        return 1;
    memset(s, -2, sizeof(signed char) * 1);
    printf("%d\n", s[0] == -2);
}
```

もしそうだとすると、このコードはmemsetを使用する以上、unsigned charからsigned charへの暗黙の型変換が発生し、処理系定義の動作とならざるを得ないと理解していいでしょうか？（私の規格の理解や、コードに問題点があればご指摘お願いします）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

１の補数系マシンってことだと２１世紀である現在は[完全に絶滅](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12855/)していますし、過去のマシンで有名どころとなると [CDC6600](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6600) とか [PDP-11](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) ってことになりそうですが

- CDC6600 は 1964 年
- PDP-11 は 1970 年
- [ANSI-C](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39922/) は 1989 年

であるため、これらのマシンに [c](/questions/tagged/c) コンパイラが実装されていたとしても C89 なり C99 なりに合致しているわけがなくて、なので言語規格書の文言を追っかけても意味がないです。

`memset()` の第二引数は `int c` なので `-2` を渡すことは問題なくできます。そして「 `unsigned char` 型に変換する」の意味は言語規格書の文言によらず単にビットパターンを変更せずに解釈を変えるだけ、つまり単純に上位ビットを無視するということで、よって `-2` のビットパターン下位ビット `1111 1101` がそのままメモリに書きこまれます。そのメモリから `signed char` として値を取り出し汎整数拡張させれば単に `-2` なので、提示命題は `1` が出力されるのでしょう。

そもそも `CDC6600` はバイト＝１２ビットだし１文字は６ビットです。なのでオイラの上記説明も成り立ちませんしそもそも C89 の文言をそのまま解釈しても話が難しくなるだけです。

その辺の絶滅した過去をいくら考えても現代マシンには適用できないし、いさぎよく忘れ去ってしまいましょう。

Comment: なるほど、、、ありがとうございます。確かに冷静に考えてみるとキャストで一々ビットパターンが変更されたらキャストだけでO(n)かかるとか、そもそも読み込み専用領域でキャストできないとか色々まずいことになりそうだな～と思いました。今の仕様の型変換の項は2の補数にしか適用できないと考えるべきなのでしょうか。整数型の項には1の補数や符号+絶対値についても書かれているのに・・・。参考リンクも勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @nora 型変換でビット化けしないことは私も説明したんですけどね…。通じなくて残念です。

Comment: すいません！( ;ㅿ; )

Answer (score 2):

> 2の補数の処理系では`1`，1の補数の処理系では`0`が出力されるのではないか

どちらの処理系においても`-2`のビット表現は一意に定まり、unsigned charへ型変換が挟まろうとビット化けするわけではない、という理解です。そのため、処理系によらず常に`1`が出力されると思います。

---

なお、C++言語ではC++20にて[符号付き整数型が2の補数表現であることを規定](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp20/signed_integers_are_twos_complement.html)されました。つまり1の補数表現をの処理系は扱わないことになっています。言語は異なりますが、特段必要なければ1の補数は忘れてもいいのかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ということは

> signed char型(8bitとします)の-2をunsigned char型にキャストした場合、1111 1101から1111 1110にビットパターンが変化する

の部分にギャップがありそうですね。
その場合どのようにしてビットパターンが保持されると考えればいいのでしょうか？

ISOでは型変換について次のように記載されていました

> 6.3.1.3 符号付き整数型及び符号無し整数型 整数型の値を̲Bool型以外の他の整数型に変換する場合，その値が新しい型で表現可能なとき，値は変化しない。 新しい型で表現できない場合，新しい型が符号無し整数型であれば，新しい型で表現しうる最大の数に1加えた数を加えること又は減じることを，新しい型の範囲に入るまで繰り返すことによって得られる値に変換する(49)。

これに従って-2を型変換すると1111 1110となるのではないかと考えました

Comment: 質問者の理解で全面的に正しいはずです。